# Ability to add "plugin" in war-mode

Tags: grails, plugins, groovy

I am lookin for a way to let the admin-role of my grails-app add a "feature"/"plugin"
to the running server, so that the system makes use of it instantly.

To be more concrete here is a small example:

```
package domains

abstract class Provider {

    def protected name;
    def protected activated = false;
    def private valid;

    def Provider( providerName ) {
        if( providerName != null ) {
            name = providerName;
            valid = true;
        else valid = false;
    }

    def isValid() { valid }
    def getName() { name }
    def isActivated() { activated }
    def setActivated( bool ) { activaed = bool }

    abstract List<String> search( String searchKey );
}
```

Some Subclass:

```
package googleprovider

import Provider;

class GoogleProvider extends Provider {

    def GooleProvider( active ) {
        super( "Google" );
        activated = active;
    }

    @Override
    List<String> search( String searchKey ) {
        return ["http://www.google.com"]
    }
}
```

Now every "plugin"/"feature" should extend from Provider and be placed as what ever file in a directory "plugins/providers/".

And the server should create an instance of this GoogleProvider on an "onAdd"-event or something leashed by that admin.

Is there any chance this could be done? Or am I totally dreaming?
If it is somehow possible and it's just that I am going a completly wrong direction,
just tell me! ;-)

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you look for plugins that registers new Artefacts, so in your startup you can lookup for this classes. You can also create a folder in grails-app to store the providers classes.

See the [Grails Dao Artefacts](https://github.com/laurobecker/grails-dao-artefacts) plugin, for example. It creates the `daos` folder inside `grails-app`, and consider all classes as a DAO Artefact. You also gain the ability of use Depenceny Injection in your classes (e.g. services).

**Some points to look**

- [Install Script](https://github.com/laurobecker/grails-dao-artefacts/blob/master/scripts/_Install.groovy) creates the directory
- You have [some classes](https://github.com/laurobecker/grails-dao-artefacts/tree/master/src/java/br/com/organicadigital/daoartefacts) that declare the Artefact
- The [plugin descriptor](https://github.com/laurobecker/grails-dao-artefacts/blob/master/DaoArtefactsGrailsPlugin.groovy) is responsible to register them as Spring Beans

**More info in**

- [Grails developer wiki](http://grails.org/Developer+-+Artefact+API)
- [Blog post with example](http://ldaley.com/post/653190105/putting-the-artefact-api-to-work-in-your-grails-app)

Comment: I've read a little bit of it, but it seems like it'll take some time to get this up and running.
It actually looks very interesting and I will spend more time with it when I have some more free time. Just not now as my project has to be finished by friday.
Anyway thanks for this information!